# Authentication when Get Azure DevOps Project Work Items using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to get all the work items for a project in Azure DevOps.

The issue I am facing is of  is authentication. How do I authenticate/login before sending this post request?

The docs show security as `0auth2` . However, I have a personal access token...what would be the correct approach? How to send an authenticated POST request that is. Do I have to register the application and get `0auth` Token etc..or PAT would suffice?

```
import requests
import base64

pat = 'nbq'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization
}
# response = requests.get(url="https://dev.azure.com/company/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1", headers=headers).json()

data = {
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task'"
}
wo_it = requests.post('https://dev.azure.com/company/example_project/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1',data=data)
print(wo_it.text)
```

Comment: You can refer to [How to extract WorkItems from query in VSTS (Azure DevOps) with Python REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810441/how-to-extract-workitems-from-query-in-vsts-azure-devops-with-python-rest-api) and [How to get all work items(Epics, Features, Issue, Task, Test Case, User Story, etc) for an Azure Devops project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54302077/how-to-get-all-work-itemsepics-features-issue-task-test-case-user-story-e)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I saw this. This is asking for a query for the functions. Is that the same query which I have in the `data`? Isn't there a way to make this work with `requests`?

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I am getting the project names from the commented out line in the code. I want to get `work-items` for those projects using requests. Will that work? I have looked at many answers however,  I cannot figure out  a way to send an authenticated POST request.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT This is exactly what I am using. However, when I send the POST request I get Sign-In..

Comment: @DeepDave-MT This is more of a python/how to make the POST request issue. One question only. Will PAT work in a POST request? How? That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps REST API supports several different auth ways, e.g. OAuth 2.0, Azure AD auth, PAT.

For the specific API `_apis/wit/wiql` you are using, using PAT is enough, you don't need to register the app. And you should know OAuth 2.0 and Azure AD auth are both user-interactive way, if you want to call the API in python with non-interactive way, PAT is the option.

PAT uses the basic auth, you need to base64 encode it and pass the encoded one to the request body every time when you send the API request. I saw you just use the token when listing the projects, but you didn't use it when call `_apis/wit/wiql`, you need to do it also, then it will work.

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops